# OWL : how to restrict range with some values in an other property

Tags: semantic-web, owl, protege, rdfs

I have a class Selfie, an objectProperty personPicture (domain Picture, range Person) to explain who is on the picture, and a dc:creator. I want to say that a selfie must have at least 1 personPicture, and the dc:creator should be someone in the list of personPicture. I tried :

```xml
<owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/leo/ontologies/album#Selfie">
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/leo/ontologies/album#Picture"/>
    <rdfs:subClassOf>
        <owl:Restriction>
            <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/leo/ontologies/album#personPicture"/>
            <owl:minQualifiedCardinality rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#nonNegativeInteger">1</owl:minQualifiedCardinality>
            <owl:onClass rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/leo/ontologies/album#Person"/>
        </owl:Restriction>
    </rdfs:subClassOf>
</owl:Class>
```

but it doesn't work. I can have a selfie without personPicture and I absolutely don't know how to do the second trick!

Answer (score 3):

Your axioms are easier to read in Manchester syntax, where they are:

Selfie SubClassOf Picture
    Selfie SubClassOf personPicture min 1 Person

The second says that each Selfie is related to at least one Person by the property personPicture.  That's *consistent* with a dataset like:

x a Selfie .

Even though it doesn't specify *which* Person x is related to by personPicture, a reasoner will correctly infer that there is one.  That's part of the [open-world assumption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-world_assumption) that is adopted in OWL.  Just because something isn't know does not mean that it is false.

As for your second condition, I'm not sure that you can express it in OWL.  You might be able to the axiom that "**if** a picture's creator is in the picture, **then** the picture is a Selfie", but that's the other direction from what you're asking.

Comment: Ok, so i m right for the first, i'm on protege with a reasoner, but i can still create some selfie without personPicture, and when i start reasoner, no error...
Thanks !!

Comment: @user2212090 Yes, that's the open world assumption at work.  You're not creating a selfie without a personPicture, you're creating a selfie for which you don't know what the value of the personPicture is.  Just like I know that you have two biological parents, even though I don't know *who* they actually are.  If you actually asserted that `x a Selfie` and `x a (personPicture exactly 0 Person)` (that is, that x actually has no personPicture values), then the reasoner would flag the inconsistency.

Comment: Joshua Taylor is right. Anything regarding validation is done by different approaches than standard OWL reasoning, e.g. SPARQL, RDF Shapes, IC constraints (Pellet), etc

Comment: An SWRL rule should be able to add the assertion that, if x is a Selfie and x has a `dc:creator` value y, then y is also a Person and `x picturePerson y`